# Optimize if -else statement Ask

Tags: c#, optimization

I have below if-else statement, and I want to optimize it more.
Is there any way to optimize it more

```
if(entity[attributeName] != null)
{
    if (entity.FormattedValues.Contains(attributeName) && entity[attributeName].GetType() != typeof(EntityReference))
    {
        return entity.FormattedValues[attributeName];
    }
    else
    {
        return GetDisplayObjectFromRawValue(entity[attributeName]);
    }
}
else
{
    if (entity.FormattedValues.Contains(attributeName))
    {
        return entity.FormattedValues[attributeName];
    }
    else
    {
        return GetDisplayObjectFromRawValue(entity[attributeName]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Optimize it *for what*?  Time? Memory? ease of understanding? Maintainability? Robustness?

Comment: If you want to make it less long in terms of code, what about `if (entity.FormattedValues.Contains(attributeName) && (entity[attributeName] == null || entity[attributeName].GetType() != typeof(EntityReference)))` and `else`? If you want something else, you might need to tell us a bit more about the types involved, and what you actually want.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. It is very hard to give suggestions without knowing what `entity.FormattedValues` **is**. The most _obvious_ issue with your code is your use of `Contains`. In 99% of code, `Contains` should be replaced with `TryGetValue`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand you mean correctly, your code can be rewritten like this:

```
if(entity[attributeName] != null)
{
    return entity.FormattedValues.Contains(attributeName) && entity[attributeName].GetType() != typeof(EntityReference)
        ? entity.FormattedValues[attributeName]
        : GetDisplayObjectFromRawValue(entity[attributeName]);
}

return entity.FormattedValues.Contains(attributeName) 
        ? entity.FormattedValues[attributeName]
        : GetDisplayObjectFromRawValue(entity[attributeName]);
```

P/S: This way has nothing to do with: it made the code run faster or it saves memory while running or something like that. Just for readability.

Comment: @mjwills Sorry, I've tried to use C# 6 with `?` operator to check `nullable` (`entity[attributeName]?.GetType()`) but it makes the code hard-to-read. By that way, we need to use `?:` operator multiple times, and all of them should be inline. It's awful.

Comment: `var bob = entity[attributeName];` is an example of what you could do. Then use `bob`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for length of code, you could rewrite it like so:

```
if (entity.FormattedValues.Contains(attributeName) 
        && (entity[attributeName] == null || entity[attributeName].GetType() != typeof(EntityReference)))
{
    return entity.FormattedValues[attributeName];
}
else
{
    return GetDisplayObjectFromRawValue(entity[attributeName]);     
}
```

Or expressed as a ternary statement:

```
return entity.FormattedValues.Contains(attributeName) 
            && (entity[attributeName] == null || entity[attributeName].GetType() != typeof(EntityReference))
    ? entity.FormattedValues[attributeName]
    : GetDisplayObjectFromRawValue(entity[attributeName]);
```

I've simplified your original code down to boolean values in an example [here](https://rextester.com/BXBAN61020):

- `v1` (entity[attributeName] != null),
- `v2` (entity.FormattedValues.Contains(attributeName))
- `v3` (entity[attributeName].GetType() != typeof(EntityReference))

Note that you should generally write your code in a way that promotes legibility over brevity.

Comment: Perfect! This answer is better than mine. OP should change the accept answer button to this answer.